# How easily add subtotals in Django

Tags: django, sum, subtotal

I use Django 1.7.8

I have `models.py`

```
class SaleDetail(models.Model):
    quantity = models.PositiveSmallIntegerField(_('quantidade'))
    price_sale = models.DecimalField(

    def get_subtotal(self):
        return self.price_sale * self.quantity

    subtotal = property(get_subtotal)


>>> from vendas_project.vendas.models import SaleDetail
>>> from django.db.models import Sum, F, FloatField

>>> q = SaleDetail.objects.values('price_sale', 'quantity').filter(sale=1)
>>> q.aggregate(Sum(F('price_sale') * F('quantity')), output_field=FloatField())
```

**Generate Error**

```
field_list = aggregate.lookup.split(LOOKUP_SEP)
AttributeError:
    'ExpressionNode' object has no attribute 'split'
```

How easily add subtotals in Django

I need the result, example:

```
price_sale quantity subtotal

10.50      2        21.00

9.55       3        28.65

total = 49.65
```

How easily add subtotals in Django

Answer (score 1):

I know this is late, but for anyone who stumbles upon this I'm sure it is a problem with `>>>q.aggregate(Sum(F('price_sale')*F('quantity')), output_field=FloatField())`.

the output_field named argument is a parameter of Sum, not aggregate so it should be `>>>q.aggregate(Sum(F('price_sale')*('quantity'), output_field=FloatField()))`. I know you said 1.7--outdated now-- but the [1.9 docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/topics/db/aggregation/#cheat-sheet) on aggregation make this clear. But it is a small mistake that I made too.